# Simple Interest Calculator calculate button error

Tags: android, calculator

I am very new to Android development and have been trying to make a simple interest calculator. It uses a SeekBar to take the number of years input. The App crashes as I click the Calculate Button.

I am using Eclipse and trying to run the app directly on the device without any emulator.

```
package com.sevendaytutorials.interestcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    private EditText principal_amount;
    private EditText rate;
    private SeekBar seekbar;

    private TextView seekBarValue;
    private Button calculate;
    private TextView result;

    private String Principal, Rate;
    private int number_of_years;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        principal_amount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.principal_amount);
        Principal = principal_amount.getText().toString();

        rate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.interest_rate);
        Rate = rate.getText().toString();

        seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


        seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_of_years);



        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_textview);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == calculate) {
            Calculate();
        }

    }

    private void Calculate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double p = Double.parseDouble(Principal);
        double R = Double.parseDouble(Rate);
        double r = R/100.0;
        double A = p*(1+r*number_of_years);
        double I = A - p;
        result.setText("The amount of interest after " +
                Integer.toString(number_of_years)+" year(s) would be " + Double.toString(I));

    }



    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        seekBarValue.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
        number_of_years = progress;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }
```

Comment: please post a stack trace

Comment: make sure you aren't passing null.

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: see my answer. besides you need to post your logcat to get help.

Comment: show your logcat errors.

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate(), you did these-

```
Principal = principal_amount.getText().toString();
```

and

```
Rate = rate.getText().toString();
```

Now both of your values are `null` as nothing are typed during `onCreate()`

Now when are you calling `Calculate()`, you are doing these-

```
double p = Double.parseDouble(Principal);
double R = Double.parseDouble(Rate);
```

as we can see, you didn't assign any proper value to `Principal` & `Rate` yet anywhere, so you should get `Exception` at these lines. you should modify to-

```
private void Calculate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Principal = principal_amount.getText().toString();
        Rate = rate.getText().toString();
       if (Principal == null || Principal.isEmpty() || Rate  == null || Rate .isEmpty())
       {
            // user are yet to fill the edittext, validation error
       }else{

          double p = Double.parseDouble(Principal);
          double R = Double.parseDouble(Rate);
          double r = R/100.0;
          double A = p*(1+r*number_of_years);
          double I = A - p;
          result.setText("The amount of interest after " +
                Integer.toString(number_of_years)+" year(s) would be " + Double.toString(I));
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Local variables

```
SeekBar seek1, seek2, seek3;
float amount, rate, time, interest, total;
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;
Button calculate;
String val, val1, val2, inter, totall;
```

> In onCreate() find ids

```
seekBar1 = findViewById(R.id.seek1);
seekBar2 = findViewById(R.id.seek2);
seekBar3 = findViewById(R.id.seek3);
calculate = findViewById(R.id.calculate);
tvAmount = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tvRate = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tvtime = findViewById(R.id.tv3);
tvEMI = findViewById(R.id.tv4);
tvInterest = findViewById(R.id.tv5);
```

> Apply setOnClickListener() on Button

calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

> Apply setOnSeekBarChangeListener() using anonymous class and implement
>   all methods

```
seek1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()    
{
```

> Get Value of SeekBar in String Variable and set on text view.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
val = String.valueOf(1000 + i * 1000);
tv1.setText(val);
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{

}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{
}
});
seek2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{                 

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
val1 = String.valueOf(5 + i * .5);
tv2.setText(val1);
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{
}
});
seek3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
val2 = String.valueOf(i);
tv3.setText(val2);
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
{
}
});
```

> Set maximum limit of Seek Bars

```
seek1.setMax(99);
seek2.setMax(30);
seek3.setMax(100);
```

> Implement onClick() for button click Action

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
calInterest();
tv4.setText(": ₹"+inter);
tv5.setText(": ₹"+totall);
}
```

> Create a method for calculation calInterest() which is called at time
>   of button Click see onClick()

```
public void calInterest()
{
amount = Float.parseFloat(val);
rate = Float.parseFloat(val1);
time = Float.parseFloat(val2);
interest = (amount * rate * (time / 12))/100;
total =interest+amount;
inter = String.valueOf(interest);
totall = String.valueOf(total);
}
```